# simple_form - override default input "type" mapping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, simple-form-for

simple_form is generating "type='number'" on the input field for any integer attribute, instead of type='text'. As this causes Chrome to show a counter control, I'd rather make it just use type='text' as the default for numbers.

It seems to be possible to override defaults in config/intializers/simple_form.rb, but it's not clear from the docs how to do this exactly. What's the syntax to set numberic columns/attributes to render as type='text'?

Comment: not quite understood what really you wish...

Comment: I didn't notice the input field was escaped out, fixed now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can override the default mapping on a per-field basis by specifying an input type:

```
<%= f.input :age, as: :string %>
```

(The full list of mappings is [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#available-input-types-and-defaults-for-each-column-type).)

But if you want to eradicate numeric inputs from your project, try:

```
# config/initializers/simple_form.rb (before/after the SimpleForm.setup block, if this exists) 
module SimpleForm
  class FormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    map_type :integer, :decimal, :float, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput
  end
end
```

Comment: `SimpleForm::FormBuilder.mappings` returns among other code `:date=>SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput, :time=>SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput, :datetime=>SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput` however my inputs are still type date. I restarted server.

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

## Use HTML5 date, time, datetime inputs

```
SimpleForm::Inputs::DateTimeInput.class_eval do
  def use_html5_inputs?; input_options[:html5] || true end
end
```

## Use string for date, time, datetime inputs

Useful if you are going to use a datetime picker like [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/):

```
SimpleForm::FormBuilder.class_eval do
  def input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block)
    options = @defaults.deep_dup.deep_merge(options) if @defaults

    input   = find_input(attribute_name, options, &block)

    # Add native DB type as CSS class so inputs can be filtered by that
    input.input_html_classes << input.column&.type
    # Use another attribute:
    # input.input_html_options[:'data-db-type']= input.column&.type

    wrapper = find_wrapper(input.input_type, options)

    wrapper.render input
  end

  # map_type :date, :time, :datetime, to: SimpleForm::Inputs::StringInput

  alias old_default_input_type default_input_type
  def default_input_type(attribute_name, column, options)
    if column.type.in? %i(date time datetime)
      :string
    else
      old_default_input_type(attribute_name, column, options)
    end
  end
end
```

`map_type` was not needed.